# Double comparison in C#, is double.Equals() the right choice?

Tags: c#, double

I recently stumbled upon this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383871/Demystify-Csharp-floating-point-equality-and-relat

that explains why comparison between (theoretically) identical doubles could lead to unexpected results. I wonder if using double.Equals() circumvent this issue or still a workaround like the one proposed in the article is needed.

I usually compare values like

```
if(x==123d)
```

but I understand this must be avoided; I'm unsure if even

```
if(x.Equals(123d))
```

is unsafe too.

Comment: Same issue: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,bceeea32c8ba20a7,references Use decimal or something like: `var diff = Math.Abs(x - 123d);
if(diff < 0.00000001)...`

Comment: Those are the same.  You have to roll your own code to do an epsilon comparison.